# Possible to hide MediaWiki namespace from category view?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I would like to use [[category:name]] to list the articles within the category, but omit articles within certain namespaces unless the user is a member of a certain group.

Is this possible?

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Hidden_pages

Comment: But make sure to read the warning at the top. MediaWiki is not made to keep secrets.

Comment: I don't need it be kept secret, just to keep a namespace off the category view unless a user is in the admin group.
Thank you for the suggestion but that extension does not provide a patch for post 1.16 Wiki and I am running 1.20.2

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're running 1.20.2, which has group CSS and js pages, such as `MediaWiki:Group-sysop.css`. Assuming you're hiding Mediawiki pages, add

```
.page-Category_CATEGORYNAME a[href*="MediaWiki"] {display:none;}
```

to `MediaWiki:Common.css`, then add

```
.page-Category_CATEGORYNAME a[href*="MediaWiki"] {display:inline !important;}
```

to `MediaWiki:Group-sysop.css`. This does leave a spare bullet point behind though, which can only be removed with javascript as CSS3 doesn't support selecting a parent selector. For more information on that see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).